# Hosting Multiple Websites on RPi 4

Tags: server, web

So I've already set everything as for port forwarding in my router settings, I've set a static IP address for the RRi 4, and have already managed to get 1 page visible through my Pi web server.

The problem began when I went to set up the "Virtual Host" files in Apache2 to point to each domain that I plan on hosting on the RPi 4. Now no page shows, and the message I keep seeing says the following:

"404 Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian) Server at MY-PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS-HERE Port 80"
As shown in the image below (404 message):

[image]

I have website1.com inside of "/var/www/website1.com/public_html/index.php"
and I have website2.com inside of "/var/www/website2.com/public_html/index.php"

My Apache2 folder inside of directory "/etc/apache2/" looks like this:

[image]

And here is how I've set up my Virtual Host file (for website1.com) inside the directory "/etc/apache2/sites-available/Website1.com.conf":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@Website1.com
ServerName Website1.com
ServerAlias www.Website1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/Website1/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

AND the other file is a duplicate for website2.com inside of directory "/etc/apache2/sites-available/Website1.com.conf":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@Website2.com
ServerName Website2.com
ServerAlias www.Website2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/Website2/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I haven't set my DNS records for my real website domains yet, but as far as I remember, I should have been able to test on my localhost or check through my public IP address that is forwarding to my RPi 4 IP address to preview these 2 separate domains/websites.

Does it look like I've structured the Apache Virtual Hosts properly? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for formatting the code!  Could you please also edit your question to let us know the URL that produced the 404 message?

Comment: I tried accessing the pages from my both my public IP address & my Pi 4 IP address as to why I've masked the actual URL.

Comment: Well, you only masked it in one place.  Might want to visit that image again.  If you didn't include a host name in the URL, Apache can't pick a configuration file.

Comment: "I haven't set my DNS records for my real website domains yet" - so, how do you expect your webserver to know whenever it should serve `Website1` or `Website2` if the request is for `127.0.0.1/index.html`?

Comment: What's in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: This question belongs to Apache web server, not Raspberrry Pi. You should better ask at one of your sister sites handling this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual hosts depend upon a host name in the HTTP/1.1 Host: header, and so probably cannot be made to work without those DNS entries.  The browser determines the host name from the URL and sets up the correct Host: header.  Apache uses that header to select the correct virtual host.  Based on the comments, you got the 404 error because you also disabled the default page.  No default, no Host: header, 404.

For testing, you could edit the hosts file of the computer that's running the web *browser* rather than enabling the DNS, or just turn DNS on and See What Happens™.

On Win10, the hosts file is located here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`  Don't forget to remove those entries when you're done testing.

Also, I don't see in your question that you've enabled the sites.  Use `a2ensite Website1.com` (Assuming that the configuration file is `Website1.com.conf`)  Once the sites are enabled, you must restart Apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Also, I believe it's good practice to use all lowercase in those file names.  DNS will resolve host names in a case-insensitive manner, and Apache will treat them that way, but I'd worry that something else might break since the file system is *not* case-insensitive.  (Fix the DNS first.)

Comment: I thought that I would have to edit the Hosts file in my Raspberry Pi versus on Windows since I've installed the LAMP stack server on my Pi 4. Is this correct?

Comment: Edit the hosts file on the computer running the web browser, not the web server.  That's how the name will get in the HTTP header.  (And, if my answer actually corrects the problem, please don't forget to accept it; that keeps it from popping up seeking more answers.)

Comment: Yes, I have already enabled both sites using "a2ensite" & restarted Apache. I've also disabled the default 000 file as well.

Comment: Aha!  If you disabled the default, and there's no host name in the header to select a virtual site, you get a 404!

Comment: So do I need to re-enable the 000 default using sudo a2ensite? Also, when testing on my localhost, do I test through my Pi's IP address, public IP address, or do I just enter in the exact domain names for testing, and it will show the test sites on my localhost from the Virtual Hosts configurations?

Comment: I'm sorry my answer wasn't clear.  HTTP/1.1 includes a Host: header sent from the browser to the server.  The browser determines the host name from the URL that was entered, and Apache uses the Host: header to select a virtual host file.  You are going to need DNS entries for your sites, either be enabling the "read" DNS or by editing a hosts file on the machine running the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I've never done it this way. I usually use a VPS for testing. So I'm just trying to see how everything relates at this point.

Comment: We are being asked to move to chat.  I think the simplest thing is to turn on the "real" DNS for testing.

Comment: Hey Bob, so I went over to my DNS or domain company and added an "A" type record to point to my Public IP address and I'm still getting that same "404 Not Found" error message. What could it possibly be? Here is the domain address right below:

http://aceypscraperpro.com

Thanks again for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so now I figured out with the problem was. I've done EVERYTHING RIGHT, EXCEPT for having the proper permissions on the directories to enable or disable these sites. I have my permissions all messed up. Thanks for your support, Bob. I can totally understand why it would have been too difficult to pinpoint such an issue.